# .net Date period selector

Tags: asp.net, user-interface

I am looking for a .net control that allows the users of my webapp to select a period in time. Basically something like the control google provides in their analytics application, where you can select a begin and enddate in one calendarcontrol.
It doesn't even has to be ajaxenabled because it is against company guidelines to use ajax technology anyway. I already googled for it, but apparently I must be using the wrong search queries.
If anyone can tell me the name of such a tool, so I can google some more, or knows such a tool that would be great.

thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it necessarily need to be a .NET control?  The YUI date control can do this.  I've used it in a couple projects and it's quite solid.  Just throw in a couple textboxes or hidden fields to get your dates posted back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery there are a couple of options, for example:

- [eyecon jQuery datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/)
- [Date Range Picker using jQuery UI 1.6 and jQuery UI CSS Framework](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/)

Being client side widgets you will have to interact with the server only with a text box input control (and take care of the formatting and parsing on server side).